# Multiple MS ACCESS connection with threading (oledb)

Tags: c#, ms-access

Please help me since I couldn't find any solution online, i have tried to do some THREAD function to select query from one ms access database (.mdb). 
Another word..the thread function targeting to the same ms access db (.mdb) ...and it's always fail. Here is the code :

```
            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Thread th1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(method1));
                Thread th2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(method2));
                th1.Start();
                th2.start();
            }

            private void method1()
            {
                using (OleDbConnection odbConn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + dbfileName + ";Mode=Read"))
                {
                    //db manipulation1
                }
            }

            private void method2()
            {
                using (OleDbConnection odbConn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + dbfileName + ";Mode=Read"))
                {
                    //db manipulation2
                }
            }
```

Comment: Do you receive an error message?

Comment: Access databases are not designed for multithreaded use.  Your question is pointless.

Comment: @DarrenDavies ..here is the error:'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'comboBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on'...

Comment: The error is because you should not touch the foreground thread (ui) from a background thread unless you pass a reference.

Comment: @tgolisch..can you give me some example, or perhaps a web link to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) instead of `Thread`. This class is design to perform work in a background thread. If you want to update the UI after the work is finished, you can subscribe to the RunWorkerCompleted event. Your handler for this event will run on the UI thread where you can safely update UI elements.

```cs
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   BackgroundWorker bg1 = new BackgroundWorker();
   bg1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(method1);
   bg1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(method1_Completed);
   bg1.RunWorkerAsync();

   BackgroundWorker bg2 = new BackgroundWorker();
   bg2.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(method2);
   bg2.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(method2_Completed);
   bg2.RunWorkerAsync();
}

public void method1(object Sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    using (OleDbConnection odbConn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + dbfileName + ";Mode=Read"))
    {
        //db manipulation1
    }
}

void method1_Completed(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Update UI.
}

public void method2(object Sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    using (OleDbConnection odbConn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + dbfileName + ";Mode=Read"))
    {
        //db manipulation1
    }
}

void method2_Completed(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Update UI.
}
```

Note that you can use the DoWorkEventArgs Results property to pass an object from the DoWork handler to the RunWorkerCompleted handler.