# Trying to add values into MS Access database from XML Files

Tags: c#, xml, database, ms-access, oledbconnection

I am trying to create a program which can read 5 XML files and store the data inside them in a Microsoft Access Database.

This is the code : https://codepaste.net/ve4bkb

However when I run the program nothing is gets added to the database.

The ERROR message pops up when I close Form1 and I get:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' in System.Data.dll
>   in the debug box.

I think Visual studio is connecting to the database correctly as in the server explorer under data connections, I can see my table from the database complete with all the headers.

The portion of code I appear to be having problems with is as follows:

```
for (int j = 0; j < timeList.Count; j++)
{
    OleDbConnection con = new
    OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\UAVbrook\brook\UAV\UAV\Readings.mdb;Persist Security Info=False");

    String strSQL = "Insert into UAVData(Day,Time,Latitude,Longitude,Altitude,Temperature,Windspeed) values(1,@timeList[j].InnerText, @latList[j].InnerText, @longList[j].InnerText, @altList[j].InnerText, @tempList[j].InnerText, @windList[j].InnerText)";

    OleDbCommand CmdSql = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, con);
    CmdSql.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    CmdSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Day", 1);
    CmdSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", Convert.ToInt64(timeList[j].InnerText));
    CmdSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Latitude", Convert.ToDouble(latList[j].InnerText));
    CmdSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Longitude", Convert.ToDouble(longList[j].InnerText));
    CmdSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Altitude", Convert.ToDouble(altList[j].InnerText));
    CmdSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Temperature", Convert.ToDouble(tempList[j].InnerText));
    CmdSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Windspeed", Convert.ToDouble(windList[j].InnerText));


    con.Open();
    try
    {
        CmdSql.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.Message.ToString();
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
        CmdSql.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code as text instead of as an image! And there is probably more info in the (inner)exception that you show here.

Comment: Check also the content of the InnerException.Message. The one that you show is just the last exception raised in the stack

Comment: @PeterBons This should be a better paste: https://paste.ofcode.org/BNVEBuDD3ihEs93Jjrt9Vg

Comment: @PeterBons and Steve How do i check the contents of the inner exception?

Comment: @Kyle. You should paste your code in the question itself. Of course you first try to reduce if to a [mcve]. The InnerException is a property of the Exception class and has itself a Message property. You can output it via code or look at it opening the Details... link when you see the exception inside Visual Studio

Comment: @Steve I have amended my question to minimise the example. It shows another method I have used to try and solve this problem. 

I have added code into the catch to try and find the Inner Exception:
    String innerMessage = (ex.InnerException != null) 
                         ? ex.InnerException.Message
                          : "";

Comment: Do not name the parameters in that way. Use a single question mark

Comment: Also your original code runs the code above inside a separate thread. I will try to move this code inside the form1 load event (by the way, being the Thread start after the Application.Run the code executes only after you have closed the form

Comment: @Steve I have changed the brackets after values to contain single question marks like so "values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)". I still get the same message in the debug box

Comment: @Steve Yes that makes alot of sense as the exception is thrown always after i close the form

Comment: try this inside your catch block: `while(ex != null) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); ex = ex.InnerException; }`

Comment: @PeterBons I get the message "Syntax Error in INSERT INTO statement."

Comment: AH I see, you are inserting your parameters like this `@timeList[j].InnerText` instead of `@Time, @Latitude` etc.

Comment: @PeterBons I have done this to attempt to fill the database with every time value inside the XML files that my data is stored in. I have edited the line to now read:  "String strSQL = "Insert into UAVData(Day,Time,Latitude,Longitude,Altitude,Temperature,Windspeed) values(@Day,@Time,@Latitude,@Longitude,@Altitude,@Temperature,@Windspeed)";"   but i still get the same "Syntax Error in INSERT INTO statement"

Comment: Time and Day are reserved keywords. Write them as _SELECT [Day], [Time],...._

Comment: @Steve That has fixed the issue, many thanks! Now to sort out the threading...

Answer (score 0):

Time and Day are reserved keywords. Write them between square brackets as

```
String strSQL = @"Insert into UAVData
                 ([Day],[Time],Latitude,Longitude,
                  Altitude,Temperature,Windspeed) 
                  values(@day,@time, @lat,@long, @alt, @temp, @wind)";
using(OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(.....))
using(OleDbCommand CmdSql = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, con))
{
    con.Open();
    CmdSql.Parameters.Add("@Day", OleDbType.Integer);
    CmdSql.Parameters.Add("@Time", OleDbType.BigInt);
    CmdSql.Parameters.Add("@Lat", OleDbType.Double)
    CmdSql.Parameters.Add("@Long", OleDbType.Double);
    CmdSql.Parameters.Add("@Alt", OleDbType.Double);
    CmdSql.Parameters.Add("@Temp", OleDbType.Double);
    CmdSql.Parameters.Add("@Wind", OleDbType.Double);

    for (int j = 0; j < timeList.Count; j++)
    {
        CmdSql.Parameters["@Day"].Value = 1
        CmdSql.Parameters["@Time"].Value = Convert.ToInt64(timeList[j].InnerText);
        CmdSql.Parameters["@Lat"].Value = Convert.ToDouble(latList[j].InnerText
        CmdSql.Parameters["@Long"].Value = Convert.ToDouble(longList[j].InnerText);
        CmdSql.Parameters["@Alt"].Value = Convert.ToDouble(altList[j].InnerText);
        CmdSql.Parameters["@Temp"].Value = Convert.ToDouble(tempList[j].InnerText);
        CmdSql.Parameters["@Wind"].Value = Convert.ToDouble(windList[j].InnerText);
        CmdSql.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Notice also that I have removed the try/catch block to let the exception visible. In a production scenarion you should be sure to handle it correctly and show appriate error messages and also sanitize the input from the XML to be abslutely sure that all those conversion succeed before trying to insert a new record. Also this code attempts to insert many records and it is possible that you need to use a Transaction object to guarantee the all/none rule.

For the threading problem I suggest to look at this answer [Multiple MS ACCESS connection with threading (oledb)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616881/multiple-ms-access-connection-with-threading-oledb)